# How to skip a not working website in eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, try-catch, webdriverwait

I have a CSV file with IPs and passwords for cameras.
I made a script to go into the website and configure some settings.
but the problem is some of these IPs are not working so the page will return 404 not found.

I want to detect these and ignore them, because every time I face a broken page, the for loop stops.

this a portion of my code:

```
String PathofPage = "http://"+p1+"/doc/page/config.asp";
            
        driver.get(PathofPage);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        if( driver.getTitle()=="HTTP 404 Not Found")
            driver.quit();
            WebElement Username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
            Username.click();
```

It's not exiting the browser when it finds the title.

This is an example of it's not finding the website

[image: Click Here]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242066/discussion-between-resha-and-prophet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the page title you are looking for there is actually existing.
What we have seen there is the unique element with id = `http404`, so you can look for that element. As following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 4)

String PathofPage = "http://"+p1+"/doc/page/config.asp";
            
driver.get(PathofPage);
driver.manage().window().maximize();

#In case the error presented quit
try{
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "http404")))
    driver.quit();    
}
#otherwise do what you want to do there
catch(Exception e) {
    WebElement Username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    Username.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the code block to invoke `driver.quit()` probing if the title contains the expected string inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*`titleContains()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#titleContains(java.lang.String)) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
try {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains​("HTTP 404 Not Found"));
    driver.quit();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    WebElement Username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    Username.click(); 
}
```